# How to remove imageview from super view in cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstableviewcell

When I reload the `NSTableView` imageview of cell is overwrite. How to remove imageview from superview in cocoa?

[image]

I have tried below code:

```
NSImageView *tabIconImageview1=[[NSImageView alloc]initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(45, 12, 40, 40)];

[tabIconImageview removeFromSuperviewWithoutNeedingDisplay];
[tabIconImageview removeFromSuperview];
if ([strFilenames hasSuffix:@"."])
{
    [tabIconImageview1 setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"fileicon"]];
    //tabIconImageview1.image=[NSImage imageNamed:@"fileicon"];
}
else if ([strFilenames hasSuffix:@".exe"])
{
    [tabIconImageview1 setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"exeicon"]];
}
else if ([strFilenames hasSuffix:@"png"])
{
    [tabIconImageview1 setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"imageicon"]];
}
else if ([strFilenames hasSuffix:@".zip"])
{
    [tabIconImageview1 setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"zipicon"]];
}
else //if ([strFilenames hasSuffix:@"."])
{
    [tabIconImageview1 setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"foldericon"]];
}

[cellView addSubview:tabIconImageview1];
```

See my screenshot, the image is overlapped. How can I stop it in cocoa?

Comment: Do you want to replace tabIconImageview? Shouldn't you assign tabIconImageview1 to tabIconImageview somewhere? Can't you just replace the image in tabIconImageview?

Answer (score 0):

If this is a NSTableView, try to refresh "edited" cells or entire table to redraw

EDITED NSTABLEVIEW

Comment: it's Nstableview not  UITableView

Comment: Sorry. I think it's the same behavior